# Why g++/clang++ throw error "does not give a valid preprocessing token"

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, clang++, cl

Below is minimal code to reproduce problem.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  Test() {}
  void test1() { cout << __func__ << endl; }
  void test2() { cout << __func__ << endl; }
  void testPrepare() { cout << __func__ << endl; }

private:
};
#define DO_TEST(obj, testName)                                                 \
  {                                                                            \
    obj.testPrepare();                                                         \
    std::function<void(void)> test = std::bind(&Test::##testName, obj);        \
    /*test();                                                                  \
    Some other code which use test()*/                                         \
  }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  Test obj;
  DO_TEST(obj, test1);
  DO_TEST(obj, test2);
  /* code */
  return 0;
}
```

This works well and doing what is expected with cl.exe, but on g++/clang++ throwing a compile time error, as seen below:

```
g++ d.cpp
d.cpp:19:53: error: pasting "::" and "test1" does not give a valid preprocessing token
   19 |     std::function<void(void)> test = std::bind(&Test::##testName, obj);        \
      |                                                     ^~
d.cpp:26:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DO_TEST’
   26 |   DO_TEST(obj, test1);
      |   ^~~~~~~
d.cpp:19:53: error: pasting "::" and "test2" does not give a valid preprocessing token
   19 |     std::function<void(void)> test = std::bind(&Test::##testName, obj);        \
      |                                                     ^~
d.cpp:27:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DO_TEST’
   27 |   DO_TEST(obj, test2);
      |   ^~~~~~~
```

Compiler details:

- **cl.exe** Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86
- **clang++** version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1, Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
- **g++** (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Note: I do know that changing `&Test::##testName` to `&Test:: testName` would solve the issue. But I want to understand whether it's bug of cl.exe to allow the code above or if g++/clang++ throwing an error is a bug.

Comment: I think the errors are right, `::foo` on it's own is not a valid token and they should be 2 different tokens. `&Test::testName` is probably the right thing to do. Don't take my word for it though, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 so cl.exe is wrong to allow compilation with `&Test::##testName`, right?

Comment: IMO it is wrong. Again though, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: In addition to @mediocrevegetable1's suggestion: Make a `do ... while(0)` around the macros ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/s7r114nfP)) or else, when using the macros, you put a `;` after the block end `}` which isn't correct.

Comment: To enable preprocessor conformance mode, use [/Zc:preprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-preprocessor?view=msvc-160). With this option, the compiler emits a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C spec:

> each instance of a ## preprocessing token
> in the replacement list is deleted and the preceding preprocessing
> token is concatenated with the following preprocessing token. ...
> If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.

So using `##` in such a way as to not create a single token is undefined -- the compiler can give a diagnostic about it, but is not required to, and it can instead (as an extension) do something else.